# Points of discontinuity of a multivariable function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, continuity

I have the following problem:

Find all of the points of discontinuity and the points of removable discontinuity of the following function:

$f(x,y)=\left\lfloor\frac{x}{y}\right\rfloor$, where $\lfloor t\rfloor$ is the whole part of the number $t$.

It makes sense that at $y=0$ we would have a point of discontinuity and that it would not be removable, but it can't be that simple, right? I can't understand what part the whole part of the number plays either in this problem.

I would appreciate it if someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

Your function is not even defined when $y=0$ and therefore it makes no sense to say that it is discontinuous there.

On the the other hand, note that $\lim_{x\to0^-}\lfloor x\rfloor=-1\neq\lfloor0\rfloor$. Can you take it from here?

Comment: That limit is not right. If x is between 0 & 1 then it's whole part is zero. So the limit from the right should be zero. Also most calculus texts take an incorrect definition of discontinuity to include points not in the domain, so that's not a fair criticism.

Comment: Concerning the first objection, I've edited my answer. Thank you. Now, about Calculus textbooks, which examples do you have in mind? I am sure that Spivak's *Calculus* or Baby Rudin don't say that points outside the domain of the function are points at which the functions is discontinuous.

Comment: Those are real analysis textbooks

Comment: Try the two most popular calculus texts in the United States: Stewart or Thomas

Comment: @N8tron Are you saying that Spivak's *Calculus* is **not** a Calculus textbook?

Comment: Okay I've heard of spivak, but haven't personally used it. What constitutes calculus varies wildly (admittedly) but trying to lump a book whose title is "Principles of mathematical analysis" by referring to it as a baby book is off the farm

Comment: @N8tron What are you talking about? Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis* is usually called *Baby Rudin* around here, in order to distinguish it from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*.

Comment: So here's a link to reviews of spivak number one says it's an analysis book. It's pretty common for a first year of real analysis to be calculus with proof in the US. Admittedly that's not how it is most other places in the world, but they don't usually call it calculus https://books.google.com/books/about/Calculus.html?id=7JKVu_9InRUC

Comment: I know the distinction, I'm saying Rudin had no intent of baby rudin being used as a calculus book otherwise he would have titled it so.  Even at his home school UW Madison which is a top tier us university does not use baby rudin as a calculus text. They do however use lecture notes that correctly define discontinuity to not include points outside of the domain. My whole point is that in some very common mathematics texts, discontinuity is defined incorrectly so our answers should keep in mind that discrepancy.

Comment: I'm a bit confused, so if x=y then I would have a point of removable discontinuity, when x->a- and it's continuous when x->a+? Also when x!=y my function would then be continuous? And finally I would have a point of non-removable discontinuity when y=0?

Comment: @perryP If $\frac xy\in\mathbb Z$, then $f$ is discontinuous at $(x,y)$; otherwise, it is continuous there.

Comment: Are there points of removable discontinuous?

Comment: @spyer No, there aren't.